# What is the difference between calling a func from a tkinter button and calling it normally?

Tags: python, tkinter

What's the difference between

```
tk.Button(root, text='load old data', command=FixRawInput.main.__init__)
```

and

```
FixRawInput.main.__init__()
```

It seems to be some problem with the tinker images; I get this error

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

But a lot of things seem to break...

Called normally:

[image: called normally]

Called from the tkinter button:

[image: called from the tkinter button]

[if anyone wants to see the full code](https://github.com/upidapi/spanishGlosseryV2)

Comment: "image "pyimage1" doesn't exist" usually means that you've called `Tk()` more than once in your program.  Each `PhotoImage` object is associated with a specific instance of `Tk`, and simply will not work with widgets that are part of a different instance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Normally we don't call `__init__()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the differance between calling a func from a tkinter button and calling it normally?

The only difference is that anything the function returns cannot be used when called via a button, since it is called by code internal to `tkinter`. Other that that, there is no difference.

> It seams to be some problem with the tinker images (I get this error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist)

That error implies that you've created more than one instance of `Tk`. Tkinter objects (widgets, images, etc) cannot be shared between instances. If you created the image in one root window and then tried to use it in another, you will get this exact error.

---

Unrelated to the question being asked, it is *very* unusual to directly call the `__init__` function. That is a red flag that you're doing something incorrectly.